# WCF - how to add additional data to each call

Tags: wcf

I want to add a complex poco that will pass itself within each wcf call. Whats the bast practice for this case?

Comment: I have a class called "ExecutionContext" that contains data about the running context, I want to pass it to the stateless server on each request. I know about the header option but as I remember it does not support complex types and you have to manually serialize stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, check this out...

https://kinnrot.github.io/passing-complex-type-through-wcf/

Comment: This link is broken. It's best not to just answer a question with a link. Can you provide some details?

Comment: sorry... very old..see new link on answer

Answer (score 5):

Typically, the best way to do something like this is passing such "meta-information" in a WCF header. You can easily create a message inspector to extend WCF (it's really not that scary and hard to do!) which would inject the POCO class (or what of it is necessary) into every outgoing request from the client, and retrieve it from the header and validate it on the server side.

There are a number of pretty good blog post out there showing you how to create a message inspector:

- Richard Hallgren's [WCF postings](http://www.richardhallgren.com/category/wcf/)
- [Writing a WCF message inspector](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx)
- [Automatic Culture Flowing with WCF by using Custom Behaviour](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/AutomaticCultureFlow.aspx)

Check out the two relevant interfaces to implement:

- [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx) on the client side, which has a `BeforeSendRequest` and `AfterReceiveReply` message to implement
- [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) on the server side, which has a `AfterReceiveRequest` and `BeforeSendReply` method to implement

Comment: Not enough for complex data types!, I already know how, just need to write about it and put it here.